# Communicating with multiple bluetooth headphones simultaneously from mac 10.8

Tags: macos, bluetooth, openframeworks

Is it possible to communicate to multiple bluetooth headphones simultaneously from mac 10.8?

I have set up an aggregate device (via audio midi setup) with two bluetooth headphones. But when I select this as the audio output no sound is produced. I have tried both playing audio files and directly interfacing with it through Open Frameworks.